# Declaring only one class public virtual

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have a class, C, that is in a diamond with classes Base, A, and B. There is a method, Base::foo(), that is overridden in both classes A and B. When I call C::foo(), I want to call B::foo(), not A::foo().

One solution claims that the way to do this is to make A virtually inherit from Base and have B inherit normally. That way, I can achieve this without having to reimplement C::foo().

However, I have not found any other information on whether this is possible, as it seems that both A and B need to be declared virtual to avoid two copies of Base being created.

Is the proposed solution correct?

Comment: what is diamond? Is it derived or diamond?

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution? Does it work?

Comment: This is actually an item in one of the Effective C++ books, IIRC.

Comment: If `foo()` is virtual, you have little choice but to override it, as a final overrider is required in one way or another. If it is *not* virtual, and you simply want any invoke of `C::foo` to actually hit `B::foo` you can establish `using B::foo;` in `class C` without having to reimplement it.

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't work, but it was my boss (ostensibly a C++ "veteran") who proposed it so I thought I might have overlooked something. When he said it I thought it wouldn't work, went back and tried it out and sure enough it didn't. Wanted to cover the bases before I went back to him.

Comment: It might help to post some code illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly define `C::foo()` this way:

```
C::foo() {
  B::foo();
}
```